# Populating a C# / XAML combobox using EF and LINQ

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, entity-framework, xaml

I am currently creating a small test app and could do with a hand in relation to populating a drodown's list via Linq.  I am getting a runtime error and I could really do with a pointer:

c#

```
egwEntities db = new egwEntities();
var sel = from o in db.dropdownsource select new {o.machine_desc};
TxtProductFamily.ItemsSource = sel;
```

xaml:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="TxtProductFamily" Text="{Binding testfield}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="10,182,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="319"/>
```

Comment: Does it work if you fix the wrong casing ("TxtP..." vs. "Txtp...")?

Comment: What is the runtime error?

Comment: @AndyDB _I am getting a runtime error_ but where and what's the error?

Comment: Casing issue -  good spot - it was correct in the code, I made a mistake trying to format for the question.  Thank you.

Comment: Here is the error:  "Data binding directly to a store query (DbSet, DbQuery, DbSqlQuery, DbRawSqlQuery) is not supported. Instead populate a DbSet with data, for example by calling Load on the DbSet, and then bind to local data. For WPF bind to DbSet.Local. For WinForms bind to DbSet.Local.ToBindingList(). For ASP.NET WebForms you can bind to the result of calling ToList() on the query or use Model Binding, for more information see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=389592."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do like this:

```
var sel = (from o in db.dropdownsource
           select o.machine_desc).ToList();

TxtProductFamily.ItemsSource = sel;
```

or More good will be to create a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{

public string MyText {get;set;}
public string MyValue {get;set;}

}
```

and then:

```
 var sel = (from o in db.dropdownsource
            select new MyViewModel{
                                   MyText = o.machine_desc,
                                   MyValue = o.SomeColumn
                                  }).ToList<MyViewModel>();
```

and :

```
<ComboBox x:Name="TxtProductFamily" Text="{Binding MyText}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="10,182,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="319"/>
```

Comment: Thank you (yet again Ehsan) - If you're ever in Hamburg I owe you a beer (or something).

Comment: so kind of you..pleasure to help out you...:)